# How to calculate f-measure base of FPR, TPR, TNR, FNR & Accuracy?

Tags: accuracy, supervised-learning

I have false positive rate (FPR), true positive rate (TPR), true negative rate (TNR), false negative rate (FNR) and accuracy. but I don't have FP, TP, FN, TN values. Now, I need the f1-measure value.

How do I calculate the f1-measure based on FPR, TPR, TNR, FNR and accuracy?

TPR=0.96
FPR=0.04
FNR=0.04
TNR= 0.96
ACC=95.66
N(number of samples)=129013

How is the following calculated?

f1-measure=??
TP=?
FP=?
TN=?
FN=?

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/287112/how-can-calculatur-f-measure-base-of-fpr-tpr-tnr-fnr-and-acc) posted just a short time ago.

Comment: @RichardHardy this is [ON HOLD].

Comment: Yes, and it is so for a reason. This one should be put on hold, too, because it is a copy of the other one which should have been edited instead of postding a new one. Please try to follow the standard practice here of editing what needs to be edited instead of posting it anew. You still can delete this one before it gets put on hold.

Comment: @RichardHardy I tried to edit or delete the previous post, but I could not. Please delete your previous post.

Comment: I saw there was an attempt to edit the old one, with a decision pending. Was it someone else than you who did that?

Comment: @RichardHardy Yes

Comment: Well, that is odd, but then I leave it here. Would you at least care to fix capital letters etc.?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, how can it be the case that you do not have the Confusion Matrix but statistics derived from it? If you run a binary classification model you can just compare the predicted labels to the labels in the test set in order to get the TP, FP, TN, FN.

In general, the f1-score is the weighted average between *Precision* $\frac{TP}{TP+FP}$ (Number of true positives / number of predicted positives) and *Recall* $\frac{TP}{TP+FN}$,

$$f1 = 2\times \frac{Precision \times Recall}{Precision+Recall}$$.

Note that, Recall is equivalent to the *True Positive Rate* (TPR), also know as *sensitivity*. Furthermore, the *False Negative Rate* is related to the *True Positive Rate* in the following way: $FNR=1-TPR$. The *True Negative Rate* is also known as Specificity: $TNR=1-FPR$, As can be observed in your question. In order to calculate the *f1-score* we need to find the *precision* which is missing from your given values.

Precision, can also be found by the following relation:

$$Precision = \frac{Recall \times Prevalence}{Recall \times Prevalence + (1-TNR) \times (1-Prevalence)} $$

Where *Prevalence* is the ratio of positive conditions (number of positives in your test set) to the total population.
You should have the number of positive conditions in your test data, so that you may get the f1-score. Note that the f1-score does not take the *True Negatives* into account.

You may find further information here: [Confusion Matrix Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix). 
I recommend that you read it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How is TP+FP calculated?

Comment: TP+FP is the sum of positive classifications by the model. Assuming a binary case, where we aim to classify observations as either A or B. "the number of A's correctly classified as A" + "The number of B's incorrectly classified as A's".  In the Confusion matrix this is the sum total of the first column.

Comment: The problem information is in the first post. How can TP+FP and Prevalence be calculated?

Comment: The confusion matrix wiki link helps a lot.